# How do I open this RJ45 wall jack?

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, rj-45, cabling

Hi I am try to see if the cables in this RJ45 wall jack are put in correctly but I can’t seem to figure out how to open it. Does any know if this can be opened or does it have to be broken?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to *"open"* it?  The wire order can clearly be seen without any disassembly.  Instead of a visual inspection for proper punch-down, perform an electrical test, i.e. continuity checks.

Comment: It looks like someone tried to follow T568A but accidentally rolled all but the orange pair.

Comment: That's **a lot** of untwisted wire. Re-do it properly while you have everything open.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! Once I opened it I found out all the wires were completely off. Once I retired it cable test cam3 back perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translucent cover should release with a thin screwdriver blade or similar. It may pivot at the edge closest to the opening.

Let's hope that you aren't trying to get maximum speed from that CAT-x cable. It's not properly terminated based on the length of the un-twisted segments. As it's internal house wiring, you'll probably be okay.